# How do i specify text in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, regular-expression

Hi I'm building a script and i need to match text from a output file to match certain conditions but it is as if it does not look to see if it actually matches:

```
echo $RESULT | grep -q '[a-z]&[A-Z]' && [ "$RESULT" = File Received ] && RETURN="$SERVICE $FINAL 0"
echo $RESULT | grep -q '[a-z]&[A-Z]' && [ "$RESULT" = File not received ] && RETURN="$SERVICE $FINAL 1"
echo $RESULT | grep -q '[a-z]&[A-Z]' || RETURN="$SERVICE $FINAL 10"
echo $RETURN
```

When i run the script it passes the first two and gives me the 10 as output. The actual text i want to match is 'File Received'

Comment: What is the purpose of the `grep` command? the pattern '[a-zA-Z]' will match any value that contains at least one alphabetic character. It makes no sense.

Comment: Also, why do you perform these evaluations this way when you can use `if` or `case`?

Comment: @peterh then *edit and fix it* instead of leaving comments. Fixing it would reduce the noise content of the site. Leaving a comment adds to it.

Answer (score 3):

What do you expect

```
grep -q '[a-z]&[A-Z]'
```

to match? It will match `x&Y`, for example: A single lowercase char, followed by an ampersand and a single uppercase char.

You probably mean `[a-zA-Z]` matching any single upper- or lowercase letter between a and z or a whitespace. But beware that this will depend on the `locale`, thus probably rather want `[[:alpha:]]`.

But I don't know why you have this check at all. If you only compare the `$RESULT` to the given string, you know it contains letters anyhow.

Finally I recommend to doublequote your strings to be compared.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the [a-zA-z] option and i get a too many arguments result. Here is the output of $RESULT  - File Received

Comment: Did you read the last sentence? Use `[ "$RESULT" = "File Received" ]`